# Parsing invalid HTML and retrieving tag´s text to replace it

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to iterate invalid HTML and obtain a text value from all tags to change it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="oxy-toggle toggle-7042 toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-active-class="toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-initial-state="closed" id="_toggle-212-142">
   <div class="oxy-expand-collapse-icon" href="#"></div>
   <div class="oxy-toggle-content">
    <h3 class="ct-headline" id="headline-213-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-225-142">Sklizeň jahod 2019</span></h3>   </div>
  </div><div class="ct-text-block" id="text_block-214-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-230-142"><p>Začátek sklizně: <strong>Zahájeno</strong><br>
Otevřeno: <strong>6 h – do otrhání</strong>, denně</p>
</span></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all():
    print(tag.name)
    if tag.string:
        tag.string.replace_with("1")

print(soup)
```

The result is

```
<div class="oxy-toggle toggle-7042 toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-active-class="toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-initial-state="closed" id="_toggle-212-142">
<div class="oxy-expand-collapse-icon" href="#"></div>
<div class="oxy-toggle-content">
<h3 class="ct-headline" id="headline-213-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-225-142">1</span></h3> </div>
</div><div class="ct-text-block" id="text_block-214-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-230-142"><p>Začátek sklizně: <strong>1</strong><br/>
Otevřeno: <strong>1</strong>, denně</p>
</span></div>
```

I know how to replace the text but bs won´t find the text of the paragraph tag. So the texts "Začátek sklizně:" and "Otevřeno:" and ", denně" are not found so I cannot replace them.

I tried using different parsers such as lxml and html5lib won´t make a difference.
I tried python´s HTML library but that doesn´t support changing HTML only iterating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.string` returns on a tag type object a `NavigableString` type object -> Your tag has a single string child then returned value is that string, if
it has no children or more than one child it will return `None`.

Scenario is not quiet clear to me, but here is one last approach based on your comment:

> I need generic code to iterate any html and find all texts so I can work with them.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(text=True):
    tag.replace_with('1')
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="oxy-toggle toggle-7042 toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-active-class="toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-initial-state="closed" id="_toggle-212-142">
   <div class="oxy-expand-collapse-icon" href="#"></div>
   <div class="oxy-toggle-content">
    <h3 class="ct-headline" id="headline-213-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-225-142">Sklizeň jahod 2019</span></h3>   </div>
  </div><div class="ct-text-block" id="text_block-214-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-230-142"><p>Začátek sklizně: <strong>Zahájeno</strong><br>
Otevřeno: <strong>6 h – do otrhání</strong>, denně</p>
</span></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(text=True):
    tag.replace_with('1')
```

##### Output

```
<div class="oxy-toggle toggle-7042 toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-active-class="toggle-7042-expanded" data-oxy-toggle-initial-state="closed" id="_toggle-212-142">1<div class="oxy-expand-collapse-icon" href="#"></div>1<div class="oxy-toggle-content">1<h3 class="ct-headline" id="headline-213-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-225-142">1</span></h3>1</div>1</div><div class="ct-text-block" id="text_block-214-142"><span class="ct-span" id="span-230-142"><p>1<strong>1</strong><br/>1<strong>1</strong>1</p>1</span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but I will loose the HTML of the strong element. I need to replace all the strings with something else later. I will specify more my init question.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question and clarify - edited my answer, may take a look.

Comment: Thanks, but your code requires me to know the strings before hand. I wont have that luxury. I need generic code to iterate any html and find all texts so I can work with them. If you have any ideas outside of the box like converting html to json reading through that, I would like to hear any idea.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking, I just adjusted it so I replace text instead of entire tag.